# how to solve this error of Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Source type 1 not available'

Tags: objective-c

I have working on pick the photo from gallery and save in gallery

my code is

```
-(void)onclicksave:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"onclicksave");
    UIImagePickerController *picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.delegate=self;

    if((UIButton *)sender== openLibrary)
    {
        picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

    }
    else
    {
        picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imagedisplay.image=[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

}
```

but in this code run time error like

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Source type 1 not available'

so give any suggestion and source code which is apply in my code

Answer (score 18):

Well, this means what it says. `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` is a value from enum, equal to 1. You're trying to run your code on simulator or on device, that doesn't have camera.